# How the Json data process in JSONArray

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I am doing a simple java client program that can read json data for url using eclipse, I have deploy all the thing in my local PC with one server running in VMware, I didn't have any web server running in my VM and the server in my VM can retrieve the json data using http://ServerURL:PortNumber/Anything/etc but no all the JSON data return from that url are the data I want, refer below for the data I need from the URL, the data I want is **scan_all_result_i** only, I need the **scan_all_result_i** for doing some comparison

```
{  
   "data_id":"a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835",
   "file_info":{  
      "display_name":"",
      "file_size":242,
      "file_type":"Not available",
      "file_type_description":"Not available",
      "md5":"aa69ba384f22d0dc0551ace2fbb9ad55",
      "sha1":"09ceb54e65df3d3086b222e8643acffe451a6e8a",
      "sha256":"dcb46d6ae2a187f789c12f19c44bbe4b9a43bd200a3b306d5e9c1fcf811dc430",
      "upload_timestamp":"2016-11-18T09:09:08.390Z"
   },
   "process_info":{  
      "blocked_reason":"",
      "file_type_skipped_scan":false,
      "post_processing":{  
         "actions_failed":"",
         "actions_ran":"",
         "converted_destination":"",
         "converted_to":"",
         "copy_move_destination":""
      },
      "profile":"File scan",
      "progress_percentage":100,
      "result":"Allowed",
      "user_agent":""
   },
   "scan_results":{  
      "data_id":"a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835",
      "progress_percentage":100,
      "scan_all_result_a":"No Threat Detected",
      "scan_all_result_i":0,
      "scan_details":{  
         "Ahnlab":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T15:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":1,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "Avira":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":133,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "ClamAV":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T10:28:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":94,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "ESET":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":38,
            "threat_found":""
         }
      },
      "start_time":"2016-11-18T09:09:08.405Z",
      "total_avs":4,
      "total_time":250
   },
   "vulnerability_info":{  

   }
```

But I getting the error in my eclipse compiler saying that the **scan_results** is not a JsonArray, this is the error message I got in my compiler

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["scan_results"] is not a JSONArray.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:596)
    at FetchResult.main(FetchResult.java:39)  <br><br> From the Json data, it's a array format of data but I have not idea what is the error message try to told me, I bit new to JSON data as well,please guide me where is my mistake.<br><br>
```

Here is my java source

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class FetchResult {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException,ProtocolException {
       URL theUrl = new URL ("http://192.168.0.25:8008/file/a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835");
       HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) theUrl.openConnection();
       con.setRequestMethod("GET");
       con.connect();
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
       if(responseCode == 200)
       {
          try
           {
             InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
             String data = "" ; 
             while((data = read.readLine() ) != null )
             {
                 buffer.append(data);
             }

             String JsonData = buffer.toString();
             JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(JsonData);
             JSONArray jarr = jobj.getJSONArray("scan_results");
             JSONObject Finaljobj = jarr.getJSONObject(0);
             int scan_result = Finaljobj.getInt("scan_all_result_i");

             if(scan_result == 0 )
             {
                 System.out.print("Start to copy file");
             }
```

Comment: post your whole json structure response

Comment: @PavneetSingh - I post out my whole JSON data structure

Answer (score 0):

If you read your Exception carefully you will get your error :  **is not a JSONArray**.

**Error Message** :-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["scan_results"] is not a JSONArray.
```

**Reason behind Exception** :-

```
"scan_results":{    // this tag-key contains complex JsonObject not JSONArray at any level.
      "data_id":"a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835",
      "progress_percentage":100,
      "scan_all_result_a":"No Threat Detected",
      "scan_all_result_i":0,
      "scan_details":{  
         "Ahnlab":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T15:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":1,
            "threat_found":""
         },
```

Exception will raise at this line actually

```
 JSONArray jarr = jobj.getJSONArray("scan_results");
```

just becuase there is no Array at any level inside your complete json data that you added in you Question.

Here, `tag-key` named `scan_results` contains complex `JSONObject` inside not an array. because tag `scan_results` contains `{`(Object Notation) not `[`(Array Notation).

So, Replace this code

```
 JSONArray jarr = jobj.getJSONArray("scan_results"); // scan_results contains jsonobject not array.
```

with

```
JSONObject jarr = jobj.getJSONObjcet("scan_results"); //this might help you out.
```